# openCV not accept numpy array?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I want to do a `matchTemplate` from a screenshot (with mss)

```
from mss import mss
import cv2

import numpy

with mss() as sct:
    screenshot_numpy = numpy.array(sct.shot())
    template = cv2.imread('./templates/player.png')

    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot_numpy,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot_numpy,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
TypeError: image data type = 18 is not supported
```

Comment: As pointed out, I guess you need to change dtype there. And that I am guessing would be `np.uint8`.

Comment: @Divakar but cv should read the numpy array and it can render the image in a window...

Comment: numpy not leave me do it :( 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: If `screenshot_numpy =  (numpy.asarray(sct.shot()) / 256).astype(np.uint8)` works, I'll write up an answer for it.

Comment: not works TypeError: ufunc 'divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to
any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: in mss documentation says the screenshot is the same type of an PIL image but with an alias for not have problems with PIL

Comment: `.shot()` *saves* an image, it doesn't return the image data. `.grab()` grabs all the image data and returns a PIL `Image`, so you should be able to do `numpy.asarray(sct.grab())`. If that still doesn't work, then access the `rgb` property of the `Image` with `sct.grab().rgb` although for reference note that these libraries (like most) keep the image in RGB order, while OpenCV uses BGR order, so you'll need to use `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)` before using it with OpenCV functions.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Works !

Comment: Great, I'll write it up as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`mss` examples page](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/en/dev/examples.html):

> `img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))`

So here we can see the `.grab()` method to get the raw pixel data from the image. In this case `sct.grab()` returns a PIL `Image`, and `numpy.array(Image)` will thus convert the PIL `Image` object into a `numpy ndarray`.

Check the `numpy ndarray dtype` after you convert; for e.g. if your code is `ndarray_img = numpy.array(sct.grab())`, then check `ndarray_img.dtype`. If it's `np.uint8` then you're done. If it's `np.uint16`, then you'll have to divide by 256 and convert to `np.uint8` with `ndarray_img = (ndarray_img/255).astype(np.uint8)`.

Further down you'll see another example which flips the R and B channels of the image:

> `cv2.imshow(title, cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))`

except this is actually backwards. It really doesn't matter because either way it's just swapping the first and third channel, so `BGR2RGB` and `RGB2BGR` do exactly the same thing, but PIL (and other libraries) give you RGB order while you need BGR order to display with OpenCV, so technically it should be

> `cv2.imshow(title, cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))`